# How do I set up a build-script with Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

How do I tell Maven, what method/class to run and how do I tell it, what classes it should import and where?

I have to use the Eclipse Maven Plugin and I dont quite understand, how to input the commands. Do I alter the pom-file or are there any buttons for it or do I use the command line.

I`ve tried to find information about it, but because I have to use the eclipse Maven tool I seem to not find what im looking for.

My file structure

```
|
|- src
|   |
|    - serie04 
|        |
|         - callee
|             |
|              - Callee.java
|         - caller
|             |
|              - Caller.java
|- classes
|- jars
```

My two Java classes:

```java
package serie04.callee;

public class Callee {
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Callee says: You called me!");
   }
}
```

```java
package serie04.caller;

import serie04.callee.Callee;

public class Caller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callee callee = new Callee();
        callee.callMe();
    }
}
```

I want that the a jar is created in the jar-File and that it prints "Callee says: You called me!" on the command line.

Comment: Do you mean specifically how to tell Maven to set up a jar that you can run with `java -jar`?

Comment: Yes I do. How do I tell maven what classes he shall use?

Comment: It tells me that I did not add anything so the jar will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

When using Maven, you are better off sticking to defaults- in example, the source code goes under `src/main/java`.

You could start a new Maven project from scratch. Using Eclipse menus, go to `File > New > Other..` and then select `Maven>Maven Project`; click `Next`. In the next page, check the `Create simple project` combobox and click `next`. Use "sample" and "sample" as groupId and artifactId; then click `Finish`.

You now have a "sample" project in Eclipse; this project is Maven-based. Put your code under `src/main/java`. If you copy/paste the sources from Windows, you will then need to `Refresh` your project.

Now the project can be compiled from the command line using `mvn package` (try it..) and a `jar` file is produced by the build, but you need the manifest (needed to run `java -jar ..`) .

---

To add the manifest, have a look at this answer: [How can I create an executable JAR..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=1)

After editing, your `pom.xml` will look like the one below. Build using `mvn package` from the cmd line. Run with `java -jar sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>serie04.caller.Caller</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

**Edit**
The location for the sources can be customized, using the `build.sourceDirectory` as below

```
..
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      ....
..
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, but I have to use the directory as I wrote in my question. How do I tell Maven to use my path instead of the defaults?

Comment: If you really need to, you can specify the `sourceDirectory`; see the update.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. However I must not create a new project. I am only allowed to create a buildscript.

Comment: uhm, if your build script uses Maven, you need a `pom.xml` file anyway- you can take the `pom.xml` and place it in your main project folder. The build script itself will just call `mvn clean package` .